# Separation between columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, columns

I am trying to create a scientific poster (in a beamer environment) with three columns. It works very well, my only problem is that the separation between the columns is too large and I cannot find a way to overwrite the default value assigned by beamer.

I know, in a tabular environment, I could have used `\renewcommand\tabcolsep{6pt}`
Is there anything similar for a `column`environment?

I use `\begin{columns} \column{.3\textwidth}` for my columns. And I use the `beamerposter` package, but from my understanding it is embedded in a `beamer` document class, so I assume that beamer's commands would work as well.

Thank you.
Here is a working example. You can see that the space between two columns is about 2 cm, I would like to be able to modify this space.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}


% Display a grid to help align images
\beamertemplategridbackground[1cm]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{} 
    \vspace{-40pt}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}[t]{0.305\linewidth}

\lipsum

\end{column}

\begin{column}[t]{0.305\linewidth}

\lipsum

\end{column}

\begin{column}[t]{0.305\linewidth}

\lipsum

\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you use `\begin{columns}
\column{.3\textwidth}` for your columns, though it should be doing it automatically? Can you give us an example code? Also are you using `beamer` or `beamerposter`?

Comment: I modified the question, to include more details.

Comment: Which document class are you using?

Comment: I am using `beamer`as a document class

Comment: I processed your code and I got [this](http://i.imgur.com/Si8ee.png) . Are you getting something different?

Comment: You can find a few examples from the [authors' website](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php) about `beamerposter`.

Comment: Thank you Percuss, I used your link to get me started (it's my first poster, can you tell?).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I get the same thing as you. But I would like to reduce the space between the two columns to 1cm for example (instead of 2cm). That is my original question.

Comment: @Mat D. I think the only way to decrease the intercolumn space is to make each column larger (e.g. `.33\textwidth`).

Comment: @MatD.: I've updated my answer providing a solution.

Answer (score 14):

The only way to decrease the intercolumn space is to increase the column width. You can do this manually, or you can define auxiliary lengths to do the calculations for you; in the following example, you simply set the desired value for `\MyColSep` and the `\MyColWd` will give you the column width producing the desired separation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\beamertemplategridbackground[1cm]

\newlength\MyColSep
\setlength\MyColSep{1cm}
\newlength\MyColWd
\setlength\MyColWd{0.3333\textwidth-0.6666666\MyColSep}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{} 

\begin{columns}[t]

\begin{column}[t]{\MyColWd}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{\MyColWd}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{\MyColWd}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To control the margins you can use `\setbeamersize`,a and the `onlytextwidth` option for the `columns` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\beamertemplategridbackground[1cm]

\setbeamersize{text margin left=3cm,text margin right=3cm}
\newlength\MyColSep
\setlength\MyColSep{1cm}
\newlength\MyColWd
\setlength\MyColWd{0.3333\textwidth-0.66666\MyColSep}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{} 

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}[t]{\MyColWd}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{\MyColWd}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{\MyColWd}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This code reduces the spacing between columns, but also affects the  margins. The objective is to keep the 3 cm margins on the sides (so text is not too close to the sides of my poster) but have a 1cm interval between columns (so I do not loose too much space on the poster).

Comment: @MatD. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The `onlytextwidth` to the `columns` environment is very important! That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 5):

In order to get what you want, you need to adjust *both* the outer margin of the poster and the size of columns.  If you just increase the proportion of the `\textwidth` your columns take up, you will have a much too narrow left and right margin, so you need to adjust that manually as well.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1in} % adjust as necessary
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns} 
\column{.33\textwidth} % adjust this size as necessary (or use Gonzalo's command).
\lipsum[1-5]
\column{.33\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-5]
\column{.33\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this myself (although for a presentation and not for making a poster) and the easiest solution I came up with is inserting negative horizontal space. It's a bit hacky but it provides a lot of flexibility.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns} 
\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{column}
\hspace{-0.33cm}\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{column}
\hspace{-0.33cm}\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```