# Adjust space between two columns

Tags: beamer, spacing, columns

I am trying to create columns in beamer presentation. I am using the following code:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Deep Learning  and Autoencoders}
The visualization derives from the weight normalization using the following formula for the case of $10 \times 10$ (for all 100 pixels  $ j = 1, ..., 100$):

\medskip
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
\column{.2\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{W_{ij}^{(1)}}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{100} (W_{ij}^{(1)})^{2}}} 
\end{equation}  
\column{.2\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=25mm]{images/2.jpg}
\caption{A simple caption \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
```

\end{frame}

THat code is working however, two columns are having a great space between them. how can I adjust that space.  My slide looks like:

[image]

Comment: Just increase \column{.2\textwidth} to \column{.5\textwidth} in both the places.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Try increasing the column width equally (or `\column{.2\textwidth}` for the first one and `\column{.8\textwidth}` for the second one):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Deep Learning  and Autoencoders}
The visualization derives from the weight normalization using the following formula for the case of $10 \times 10$ (for all 100 pixels  $ j = 1, ..., 100$):

\medskip
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
\column{.5\textwidth} %%width increased
\begin{equation}
    x = \frac{W_{ij}^{(1)}}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{100} (W_{ij}^{(1)})^{2}}} 
\end{equation}  
\column{.5\textwidth} %%width increased

\begin{figure}
\centering
\vrule height 3cm width 3cm
\caption{A simple caption \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok it works. One last question how can I move up the right image to be in the same level with the equation?

Comment: Do you mean bottom align with the equation?

Comment: Yes i want the equation to be in the same level of the image(in fact in the middle of image).

Comment: Use \begin{columns}[c,onlytextwidth] (note the option "c") to center

Answer (score 1):

As [Gonzalo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) has mentioned in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53027/22492) answer,

> The only way to decrease the intercolumn space is to increase the
>   column width

So you will have basically two options:

1. Change `\column{.2\textwidth}` to something bigger, e.g., `\column{.8\textwidth}` which bring the right column as close to left column as possible.
2. Remove `onlytextwidth` options which will center the `columns` hence bringing them close to each other at center.

To read more, refer to aforementioned answer.